# Create user and initialize home directory folders in owncloud

Tags: php, owncloud

I am using owncloud 7 and I want to create a custom api call  tha creates a user and initialize the user's home directory (creates some folder).

The documentation for the owncloud exists (it's the best thing I found)

http://fossies.org/dox/owncloud-7.0.2/annotated.html

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom api call I used \OCP\API::register thats the easy part.

To check if a user exists

`OC_User::userExists( $new_user_username ); // return boolean`

To create the new user

`OC_User::createUser( $new_user_username, $new_user_password );`

To create a folder inside that users home directory

First logout any logged user

`OC_User::logout();`

Then login as the new user

`OC_User::login( $new_user_username, $new_user_password );`

If you want to be sure that the new user is logged you may use

`$logged_user_username = OC_User::getUser(); // If( $logged_user_username == $new_user_username ) you are ok!`

To initialize user home directory you should run these two

`\OC\Files\Filesystem::initMounts();
\OC\Files\Filesystem::initMountPoints( $new_user_username );`

To create a new folder inside users home directory use

`OC\Files\Filesystem::mkdir( 'New folder' );`

by doing this you will create a new folder named 'New Folder' under
/data//files/New Folder

To remove a folder, lets say the photos folder created by default, use this

`OC\Files\Filesystem::rmdir( 'photos' );`

This will remove the directory
/data//files/photos

To have a clean code you have to logout the $new_user_username

`OC_User::logout();`

and relogin the user that made the api call.

You have to check who is allowed to execute such an api call.

Answer (score 1):

About the user home initialization: if the folder contents are the same for ever new users, you can create a template directory with the contents and specify it in the config.php

`/**
 * The directory where the skeleton files are located. These files will be
 * copied to the data directory of new users. Leave empty to not copy any
 * skeleton files.
 */
'skeletondirectory' => '',`